# Search in array of objects with object javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, foreach

I have an array like this

```
var userdata = [
    {"id":1,"gender":"M","first":"John","last":"Smith","city":"Seattle, WA","status":"Active"},
    {"id":2,"gender":"F","first":"Kelly","last":"Ruth","city":"Dallas, TX","status":"Active"},
    {"id":3,"gender":"M","first":"Jeff","last":"Stevenson","city":"Washington, D.C.","status":"Active"},
    {"id":4,"gender":"F","first":"Jennifer","last":"Gill","city":"Seattle, WA","status":"Inactive"}
]
```

I need to filter this array on some conditions. The form of these conditions are like this.

```
var search_object = {gender:"M",city:"Seattle, WA"}
// Gender = M and city =  'Seattle, WA'
var search_object1 = {gender:"M"}
var search_object2 = {city:"Seattle, WA"}
// This is same as above
var search_array = {status:["Active","Inactive"]}
// Status Active or Inactive
var search_array = [{status:"Active"},{status:"Inactive"}]
// Same as above
var search_object1 = {gender:"F"}
var search_array   = [{status:"Active"},{status:"Inactive"}]
//Gender = F and status = Active or Inactive
var search_object = {gender:"F"}
var search_array  = [{status:["Active","Inactive"]}]
// same as above
```

I have tried looping but failed. Please help or suggest or provide some proper links to get help.

Comment: Please post your loop.

Comment: i mean to say i am not javascript expert and failed to provide `and` and `or` to filter items

Comment: Seems like a job for the function appropriately named [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: You have to loop the array! Also the last two `search_object` are no valid Javascript objects.

Comment: thanks i think i mistyped let me edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code covers all the cases you mentioned.

```
function search(searchObj, data) {
    if(searchObj instanceof Array) {
        return data.reduce(function(prev, current, index, array) {
             return prev.concat(search(current, data));
        }, []);
    } else {
        var results = data.filter(function(el) {
             for(var prop in searchObj) {
                if(searchObj[prop] instanceof Array) {
                    if(searchObj[prop].indexOf(el[prop]) == -1) {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else
                if(el[prop] !== searchObj[prop]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        });

        return results;
    }
};

search(search_object, userdata);
```

Here is the working example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bQpz2/5/).

And here are some links to the functions I've used above:

- [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)
- [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: this returns empty result

Comment: Okay, as per your update I've updated my solution too. Now it covers all the cases. Check it out.

Comment: thanks i have tested some cases and they are working fine. I will test others when find some time

Comment: Hi! do you think you have done this condition too. `Gender = F and status = Active or Inactive`. these are surely two separate parameters. How can i combine them in to one to use it

Comment: For that search your `search object` should look like this: `{gender: "M", status: ["Active","Inactive"]}`, which gives the correct results in my code.

Comment: Thanks thats much better

Comment: +1 Very nice answer! I'm using this now for searching complex objects :) Refactored it for less bytes..

Answer (score 1):

Just what RGraham said in the comments, you can use the filter function on arrays.

```
var search_object = {gender:"M",city:"Seattle, WA"};
var filtered = userdata.filter(function(obj){
    return (obj.gender === search_object && obj.city === search_object.city)
});
filtered[0];//Array with objects that return true;
```

Comment: how can i add `obj.dynamic_column` coming from the condition not `obj.gender`